# A model of ZF in which exists an amorphous set

Tags: set-theory

I read in the book *The Axiom of Choice* by Thomas Jech that in the basic Fraenkel model (a model of ZFA, that is ZF with atoms) the set $A$ of atoms is amorphous (i.e. it is infinite but it is not a union of two disjoint infinite sets).

Is there a model of ZF (without atoms) that contains an amorphous set?

Comment: Yes. The existence of  a ZF model with an amorphous set follows from the existence of such a ZFA model by the Jech-Sochor theorem, which you can find later in Jech's book.

Comment: Also, once you've gone through what Jech calls the basic Cohen model and the second Cohen model in the next chapter, a direct construction of a model with an amorphous set of sets of reals is very similar to the second Cohen model.

Comment: @AndreasBlass: it's exercise 6.3.5 in the book but I don't know the solution. Is there some paper in which the Jech-Sochor theorem is applied to prove that existence of amorphous set is consistent with ZF?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen: is there some paper in which it's explicitely constructed a model of ZF in which an amorphous set exists?

Comment: @effezeta Not that I'm aware of. Any reason why you're focused narrowly on finding a model with an amorphous set as opposed to just learning how symmetric extensions work?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as suggested in the comments, there are several ways to approach this.

1. We can apply the Jech–Sochor transfer theorem to simply copy the amorphous set into a model of $\sf ZF$.
2. We can slightly modify the "second Cohen model" to have an amorphous set instead of a Russell set.
3. We can force over the "first Cohen model" and add an amorphous set (this was done in *Monro, G. P.*, [**On generic extensions without the axiom of choice**](https://doi.org/10.2307/2273318), J. Symb. Log. 48, 39-52 (1983). [ZBL0522.03034](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0522.03034). and this was later generalised by myself and Jonathan Schilhan in [Sequential and distributive forcings without choice](https://doi.org/10.4153/S0008439522000753).)
4. We can also modify any of the above arguments so that any fixed $V_\alpha$ will still be well-orderable, by adding an amorphous set into $\mathcal P(\kappa)$ for a suitably large $\kappa$. Note, this generally requires $\kappa$ to be regular, but starting from a model of $\sf ZFC$ this isn't a problem.

Comment: Thank you! About the first way...does the Jech-Sochor theorem allow to construct a model of ZF containing the amorphous set or it only proves that a model of ZF containing the amorphous set must exist?

Comment: You really should look at some references at some point. You can ask all the questions, and hear all the answers, but some things cannot be taught, they can only be learned.